# Can't download file from direct link with python requests

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I was trying to download a file from a direct link.  When I try the link in my browser and Postman the file is successfully downloaded.

When I tried it with python requests I received a 302 status code even with requests.get(... allow_redirects=False).  When I check resp.headers["location"] it returns a different link.  Here is what I did. I hid the real link for privacy reasons.

```
...

url = "https://store10.gofile.io/download/******************/test.txt"

resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
print(resp.headers['location']==url) Prints "False"

with open(out, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Maybe set stream=True in requests.get().  Also are you sure thats the direct link?

Comment: I did that and it's not working.  When I open that  link in my browser it immediately starts downloading. @den0

Comment: That example works when I try to download from one of my own links.  I think there may be something wrong with that link.  Maybe use this python package https://pypi.org/project/gofilepy-api  Might make it easier to download files.

Comment: Without the actual link -- or another link that you can share that reproduces the problem -- we're all just guessing. This could easily be something on the server that is being triggered e.g. by matching against your user-agent header or other aspects of the request.

Comment: I will try out the library thanks. @den0